# AngularJS - How to sum filtered grandchild items in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, ng-bind

I created a kanban board app with Angular, now I'd like to put the sum of filtered Post-Its points, and a count, like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">

<div ng-init="col.TotalPoints = 0" ng-repeat="col in columns">
    <h3>{{col.Title}} - ({{ col.TotalPoints?? }} Pts.)</h3>
    <div ng-init="subCol.Points = 0" ng-repeat="subCol in col.SubColumns">
        <h3>{{subCol.Title}} - {{ subCol.Points }} Pts.</h3>
        <div ng-show="false" ng-bind="subCol.Points= (filteredPostIts| sumPointsFilter:'Points')" ></div>
        <div ng-repeat="postIt in filteredPostIts = (subCol.PostIts | filter:searchText)">
            <p>#{{postIt.Id}}</p>
            <p>{{postIt.Title}}</p>
            <p>{{postIt.UserName}}</p>
            <p>{{postIt.Points}} Points</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assign my filtered Post-Its to `filteredPostIts` alias, then used to `ng-bind` to use the `sumPointsFilter` to iterate over all filtered post-its and sum their points, which is working fine. The Sub-Column Points is recalculated as soon as we start filtering some post-its by typing some text in the search input.

Now I'd like to calculate the total points for the whole column, which is the sum of its subcolumns (considering the filtered post-its).

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zbrohhy/53/). The first column is "Não Iniciado" (Not started), which has one subcolumn called "Backlog". The second column is "Em andamento", which has two subcolumns ("Executando" and "Aguardando").

Try typing **marcello** for example, and it will filter Marcello's post-its, and recalculate the points for the subcolumns.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the columns and subcolumns scope variables set?

Comment: Sure I can, just wait a little.

Comment: @r0m4n I added JSFiddle, tell me if it's too complex, I tried to simplificated my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have quite a bit going on that jsfiddle but I think I see what you could do...

Reuse that same summation filter like this:

```
<h3>{{col.Titulo}} - ({{ col.Divisorias | sumPointsFilter: 'Points'}} Pts.)</h3>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/9zbrohhy/54/

Comment: This solved everything, I never thought about reusing the same filter, it was simpler than I thought. Every day I discover more and more how AngularJS is simple and powerfull at the same time. Thanks!!!